# Sub-setting an Array

Tags: arrays, perl, subset

I'm trying to use `splice` to obtain an array that is the subset of another array but something isn't working. The following code, returns a value of `67` for the pair of arguments of `splice (1, -3)` rather than the array `34 67`. Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @a = (99999, 34,67,976,432,99999);
my $length = scalar(@a);

for ($counter = 0; $counter<=$length; $counter++){
    my $max = max(-3 + $counter, 1);
    print "$max\n";
    my $second_counter = -($length - $counter);
    print "$second_counter\n";
    my @worker = splice @a, $max, $second_counter;
    print "@worker\n";
}
```

Comment: `splice @a, 1, -3` does return `(34, 67)` in that array, the problem is somewhere else in the counters, not the `splice`. The code is working, doing what you told to do :-) question: do you want the `1, -3` to be achieved in the first iteration?

Comment: cross-post at http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1141079

Comment: @sidyll No, I don't want it to be achieved in the first iteration, but I just don't understand how is it possible that the for loop doesn't return this sub-set of the initial array when it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splice removes (or replaces) what's in the array; it sounds to me like you just want to use a slice:

```
my $second_counter = $counter - 1;
my @worker = @a[$max..$second_counter];
```

but it isn't really clear to me that you are doing what you think you are with $second_counter.

Comment: @g_puffo well, I executed your code and I see that before reaching the `1, -3` the arguments pass by `1, -4`. This removes the 34 from the array. As ysth said here, don't forget that `splice` removes the elements. And in your loop when reaching `1, -3` the list is already different. In list context `splice` also returns the removed elements, so this might be confusing you?

Comment: But even if I use `my @worker = @a[$max..$second_counter];` instead of `splice` the code still doesn't return the correct subset when its time comes in the for loop. I wasn't aware that by using `splice` on `@a` I was actually changing the original array.

Comment: @g_puffo The arguments to `splice` don't work the same way in an array slice. Check your math! And look at the help for array slices. Note that ysth also changed the `$second_counter` code